# In Eclipse 4.6.3+CDT, how do I ensure the indexer ranks project headers before system ones?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

(NOTE: This is not a question about UNRESOLVED symbols; this is a question about INCORRECTLY RESOVLED symbols, and further, it is an indexer problem, not a build problem.  Our builds are done externally and work fine; we use Eclipse as an editor only, after doing a CDT import of the project.)

We are developing a Linux shared library using Eclipse neon.3 (4.6.3) and the CDT.  The library is EVENTUALLY installed to the local system, and a test app built against it, but this is not a daily occurrence.  However, once installed, those need to remain where they are.

The problem is that the indexer is finding the headers in /usr/local instead of the ones *in the project under development*.  This is exasperating, because going to a class definition winds up opening an obsolete version in a system directory.  Assuming you don't notice, you then make a bunch of changes, go to save, and get a big complaint about editing a read-only file, at which point you notice the problem.

I have been able to disable *everything*, and try manually adding all the paths, but then the problem is that the indexer can't find the C++ Standard Library headers, and the location of those potentially varies.

What is the most compact, constrained, and correct method for ensuring the indexer will always find headers within the project before it goes poking around in /usr/local?

Constraints:

1. Because the library's header files are used from within both its later-linked applications and its own internal code, these header files use include directives of this form:

   ```
   #include <my-lib/subsystem/ThingyDingy.h>
   ```
2. Toolchain-specific headers such as the C++ Standard Library should be auto-discovered.
3. Sadly, we use, and will need to continue to use, Boost.  This means the "all header variants" option, etc., need to stay on.

Freedoms:

1. If there is a sane way to exclude /usr/local/my-lib from ever being indexed for any reason, that is acceptable (e.g., it does not even need to be a fallback, any use of it at all for any reason is utterly undesirable).
2. Heuristic magic tricks can be dumped, for all I care, so long as the Standard Library and Boost can still be found and properly indexed.

Open to all suggestions, but please, please ensure you are very familiar with Eclipse neon.3 (4.6.3) with the current CDT.  We are absolutely drowning in bad suggestions from ancient versions.  Additionally, we didn't use to have nearly this much trouble with this, and it is possible that it is a recent regression, though I think the question of the BEST way to do this still stands either way.

We're going insane fighting our tools.  Send help.  Please.

Comment: Well back in version 2.66.6 you had to check the "search include project headers first" checkbox in the CDT Options->Will->Never->Be->Found->OptionsMenu.

Comment: Yeah, that's _exactly_ the kind of advice I've found so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the order of the providers in Project Settings -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths -> Providers.

Change it so that CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Setting is below, and therefore lower priority, than project local settings.

Here is my MCVE. On my machine I have `/usr/include/arpa/ftp.h` which has amongst others, the following definitions:

```
#define PRELIM      1   /* positive preliminary */
#define TYPE_A      1   /* ASCII */
```

If I create a `main.c` with these contents:

```
#include <arpa/ftp.h>

#ifdef TYPE_A
#error Wrong ftp.h!
#endif

#if PRELIM != 8
#error Wrong ftp.h!
#endif

int main() {}
```

And my "overridden" ftp.h in my project in `include/arpa/ftp.h` with the same contents, except PRELIM now == 8 and TYPE_A is commented out.

And a Makefile like this:

```
all:
    gcc main.c -o main -Iinclude
```

If I build without the `-Iinclude`, I get `#error Wrong ftp.h!` and with the `-Iinclude` everything works fine.

However, if I open my editor I get the two #ifdef blocks enabled, and therefore CDT is reporting an error.

Then go to Project Settings -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Includes tab and add my project's `include` directory to the Include directories.

Still fails, because of the order of processing.

Then go to Project Settings -> C/C++ General -> Preprocessor Include Paths -> Providers tab and move *CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings* below *CDT Managed Build Settings Entries*

As shown:
[image]

Here is a before and after settings change:[image]

Comment: Bam!  You nailed it.

We kept wondering why the "Move Up" and "Move Down" buttons on the "Entries" tab were grayed out.  (Why do those even exist?)  That caused us to miss the fact that these buttons work for the "Providers" tab, because it looks like those buttons are children of the parent dialog, not the tab.

We had to undo a bunch of other, related mistakes we'd made, and go back through the usual mess with "include all variants" for Boost, but I think this is going to work now.

Thanks very much for your thorough and accurate assistance!

Comment: I experienced the same problem again and again. By following the steps, I ended up with the choice between workspace and systemwide installed headers every time I followed a declaration, but the symbols were still wrongly indexed. I could resolve it, finally, by also adding my source directory explicitly to Properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> Source Location